# Flutter error while adding images(assets)

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-dependencies, flutter-image, flutter-assetimage

I am trying to add images to my flutter app via assets. [this is the where i have linked the images.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBpQI.png) [this is the pubspec yaml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eru6X.png) Tried different ways. nothing seems to work.

Comment: You should use Image.asset widget and then as the first parameter you put the path to your image as a String.

Comment: first change your line in pubspec -images to -assets/images then run pubget  and then u can access the images

Answer (score 1):

First of all create a folder in your project named assets, not in your lib folder. After that in pubspace.yaml define your folder like this assets/images/

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong thing in pubspace.yaml.
Maintain whitespaces as shown in below

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/
```